# Drupal Commerce and Views Trouble

Tags: views, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce and Views to make a products page that has a number of elements on it that are somewhat complex.

So far my page is a simple view that lists products as a table that also has some filters that users can modify to sort through products. However I am having trouble adding fields to that view to add the other elements i want to display.

**What i need:**

- I need to add a "Add to cart" button for each product displayed.
- I also need to add a product image that changes to the smaller displayed images when clicked.
- In addition I also want to add a number of custom text fields that do not change when the user is applying the filters to the page.

**What I have done so far:**

- I have attempted to use Views Field View and create sub views and add them to a parent view, however I am having trouble getting the sub views to show up.
- Found a couple of sites that show methods of adding "Add to Cart" buttons manually by editing the files. But i wanted to make sure there was not module for it already.

If anyone can point me in the right direction i would appreciate it.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to make a View of product display nodes, and not product entities.

The product display node has the product reference field on it, which provides the 'add to cart' formatter.

You can also show the product image and add other arbitrary text fields to the display node